# How to escape string in .aspx

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get this string to work, I can't escape it correctly or I'm using the wrong syntax " vs '

```
<a href="<%#string.Format("{0}?ItemRemove=true&iID={1}", Page, <%#Container.DataItem.Id )%>">...</a>
```

Comment: Less coffee, more properly paired string quotes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("{0}?ItemRemove=true&ID={1}", 
    Page, 
    Container.DataItem.Id) %>'>
...
</a>
```

...everything is wrapped for read-ability. It can all live on one line, of course.

Comment: can you explain to me why the ' vs. " in this case

Comment: This won't even compile, the container doesn't exist outside of a data bound context. Shouldn't <%= be <%#?

Comment: @Phaedrus - I do believe you're right. I've been working in .NET MVC for a while and my fingers were on auto-pilot...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the apostrophe around the href.

```
<a href='<%= String.Format("{0}?ItemRemove=true&ID={1}", Page, Container.DataItem.Id) %>'>
...
</a>
```